# Clicking outside of element returns JS error

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a function which detects when a user clicks outside of an element. At the moment I am working with the following code snippet:

```
var specifiedElement = document.getElementById('js-search-suggest-wrapper');

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var isClickInside = specifiedElement.contains(event.target);

    if (!isClickInside) {
        console.log('do something!');
    }
});
```

}

However I seem to be getting the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of null

Is there something wrong with my code, or could it be the way my HTML is setup?

Comment: what does this returns ... `console.log(specifiedElement);` . Your `specifiedElement` must be null thats why you are getting this error.

Comment: Error message is verbose,  `specifiedElement` is `NULL`. Do the `NULL` handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `specifiedElement` is null it is returning error, Please add a element in html with id `js-search-suggest-wrapper`

```js
var specifiedElement = document.getElementById('js-search-suggest-wrapper');

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var isClickInside = specifiedElement.contains(event.target);

    if (!isClickInside) {
        console.log('do something!');
    }
});
```

```html
<a id="js-search-suggest-wrapper">javascript</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`specifiedElement` might might be **null** . Check if the element with `js-search-suggest-wrapper` id exists or not. You can handle null in following ways.

```js
var specifiedElement = document.getElementById('js-search-suggest-wrapper');
if (specifiedElement !== null){
  document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var isClickInside = specifiedElement.contains(event.target);
    if (!isClickInside) {
      console.log('do something!');
      }
  });

} else {
  console.log('specifiedElement is null!');
}
```

```html
<div id="js-search-suggest-wrapper">hello</div>
```